# Select the first link excluding the nested links by CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to affect the first link but not the second one, how do I do this using only CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot%28%29) pseudo-class to exclude the `ul.sub` elements, then select the direct `<li>` and `<a>` child as follows:

Here you go:

```css
ul:not(.sub) > li > a {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hakawivu/6/edit)**.

Or combining Attribute selector, if the first `<ul>` doesn't have `class` attribute:

```css
ul:not([class]) > li > a {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

And if there are multiple `<li>` elements in the main `<ul>`, you can use [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) pseudo-class to select **only** the **first** list item:

```css
ul:not(.sub) > li:first-child > a {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hakawivu/5/edit)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
ul:not(.sub)>li:first-child>a{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: And this will select all the anchor tags.

Answer (score 1):

A pure css solution will be as follows

```
ul:not(.sub) > li:first-child > a
```

But the `:not` pseudo-selector is only supported in IE9 and newer.

Comment: This doesn't work, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/X8f2w/) in Chrome. This however does: `ul:not(.sub) > li:first-child > a` [modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/X8f2w/1/)...

Comment: @War10ck, yes, thanks, surely the direct descendant selector is needed.

Comment: Works for me - fantastic!!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4aA7c/

CSS:

```
ul:not(.sub) > li:first-child > a {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. I won't downvote you, but this won't work.